# ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 89

Tags: azure-devops, angular-cli, puppeteer

Using Azure DevOps, somehow the pipeline just stop working and I can't get the test done when I run `ng lint && ng e2e && ng test --watch=false`. This it's working when running local.

```
[16:43:25] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[16:43:25] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[16:43:27] E/launcher - session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 89
Current browser version is 88.0.4298.0 with binary path D:\a\1\s\node_modules\puppeteer\.local-chromium\win64-818858\chrome-win\chrome.exe
  (Driver info: chromedriver=89.0.4389.23 (61b08ee2c50024bab004e48d2b1b083cdbdac579-refs/branch-heads/4389@{#294}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)
[16:43:27] E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 89
Current browser version is 88.0.4298.0 with binary path D:\a\1\s\node_modules\puppeteer\.local-chromium\win64-818858\chrome-win\chrome.exe
  (Driver info: chromedriver=89.0.4389.23 (61b08ee2c50024bab004e48d2b1b083cdbdac579-refs/branch-heads/4389@{#294}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
    at D:\a\1\s\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:769:24)
    at Function.createSession (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\chrome.js:761:15)
    at Direct.getNewDriver (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\direct.js:77:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:195:43)
    at D:\a\1\s\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:339:29
    at _fulfilled (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at D:\a\1\s\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at D:\a\1\s\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
[16:43:27] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.
```

This is how I set the pipeline task

**puppeteer**

```
cd node_modules/puppeteer
npm install
npm install webdriver-manager@latest
```

```
> puppeteer@5.5.0 install D:\a\1\s\node_modules\puppeteer
> node install.js

Chromium is already in D:\a\1\s\node_modules\puppeteer\.local-chromium\win64-818858; skipping download.

> puppeteer@5.5.0 prepare D:\a\1\s\node_modules\puppeteer
> node typescript-if-required.js

added 848 packages from 915 contributors and audited 860 packages in 43.745s

96 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

Finishing: npm install puppeteer
```

**ng test**

```
ng lint && ng e2e && ng test --watch=false
```

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question, If yes, you could accept it as an answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks. If not, please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the doc: Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Datacenter and Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. We find there is only ChromeDriver 88.0.4324.96 on our hosted agent.

So we have two suggestions:

1. We noticed that the test is working well on your local machine, so we can try to install a self-agent in your local machine and use the new agent to try again.
2. We can add a bash task and use the below the script to install latest version of the ChromeDriver first.

   npm install chromedriver --chromedriver_cdnurl=https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/89.0.4389.23/chromedriver_win32.zip

[image]

Comment: It did work in the past. Now I'm having the same problem but with a new version https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68575267/this-version-of-chromedriver-only-supports-chrome-version-93

Answer (score 0):

since you are using javascript

yarn add chromedriver --chromedriver-force-download

or

npm install --save-dev chromedriver --chromedriver-force-download

https://github.com/giggio/node-chromedriver/issues/311