# This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 93

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, puppeteer

I have a Angular project which runs Karma with puppeteer, and once in a while I get the following error

```
[11:13:43] E/launcher - session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 93
Current browser version is 92.0.4515.107 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
  (Driver info: chromedriver=93.0.4577.15 (660fc11082ba57405eca2e8c49c3e1af756fbfae-refs/branch-heads/4577@{#203}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)
[11:13:43] E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 93
Current browser version is 92.0.4515.107 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
  (Driver info: chromedriver=93.0.4577.15 (660fc11082ba57405eca2e8c49c3e1af756fbfae-refs/branch-heads/4577@{#203}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
    at D:\a\1\s\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:769:24)
    at Function.createSession (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\chrome.js:761:15)
    at Direct.getNewDriver (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\direct.js:77:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:195:43)
    at D:\a\1\s\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:339:29
    at _fulfilled (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at D:\a\1\s\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at D:\a\1\s\node_modules\q\q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
[11:13:43] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

It seems that happens every time [chromedrive](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) lunches a new version.

This is my setup

*e2e/protractor.conf.js*

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    process.env.CHROME_BIN = require('puppeteer').executablePath();
  
    config.set({
      basePath: '',
      frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
      plugins: [
        require('karma-jasmine'),
        require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
        ...
      ],
      ...
      browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
      ...
      customLaunchers: {
        headlessChrome: {
          base: "ChromeHeadless",
          flags: [
            "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
            "--disable-extensions",
            "--disable-gpu",
            "--disable-web-security",
            "--headless",
            "--js-flags=--max-old-space-size=8196",
            "--no-proxy-server",
            "--no-sandbox",
          ],
        }
      }
    });
  };
```

And my question is, Is there a config to avoid the error every new [chromedrive](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) version?

[ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 89](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66479989/chromedriver-only-supports-chrome-version-89)

Comment: Apparently today started to work again without changes

Comment: Yes, the same happend to me yesterday, and today the test in Protractor (in local) is running well, it does not download the chromedriver version 93 anymore, it is downloading the 92 and all is fixes now. At least in local.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and every time a new release was launched, you need to download and put into your driver path or similar, i dont know if exist a command with pip to did it easier.
[Chrome Driver version Download](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)